# Microsoft SQL Server Date compare

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a subject like this. I have a table in the database. I have two columns in the table named Startdate -Finishdate.

What I want to do now is this. If the records I will create next are among the previously created records, the record will not be discarded.

For example startDate = '2022-11-10' finishdate = '2022-11-15' = YYYY-MM-DD

The next record I want to create is Startdate = 2022-11-07 finishdate = 2022-11-12

I don't want him to make such a record here. Between the start and end dates of the previous record, the start date of the new record I will make is the start date. I don't want it thrown in this case.
but if it is another case.
The end date of the new record can be the start date of the next record.

I tried a sample sql with the between command, but it didn't work.

I look forward to your valuable opinions on the subject.

```
DECLARE @UserId nvarchar(max) = '26046958'
DECLARE @CompanyCode nvarchar(max) = '0601'
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2022-11-07'
DECLARE @FinishDate datetime = '2022-11-12'


SELECT * FROM PreApprovedExpense (nolock)
WHERE UserId = @UserId
and CompanyCode = @CompanyCode
and (SELECT CONVERT( date, @StartDate ,23)) >= (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), 
CAST(StartDate as date), 23) where UserId =@UserId) and  (SELECT CONVERT( date, 
@StartDate ,23)) < (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), CAST(FinishDate as date), 23) where 
UserId =@UserId)
or (SELECT CONVERT( date, @FinishDate ,23)) >= (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), 
CAST(StartDate as date), 23) where UserId =@UserId) and  (SELECT CONVERT( date, 
@FinishDate ,23)) <= (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), CAST(StartDate as date), 23) where 
UserId =@UserId)
code here
```

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are different products. Dates, both in SQL Server and ASP.NET have no format, they're binary values. If you have date-typed fields, just compare them directly without conversions. If not, you have a major bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: As for `(nolock)` that's *always* a bug in itself, hinting at more serious bugs in the rest of the query or application. It's not a `go fast` switch. It's a `read dirty and duplicate data while randomly throwing errors` feature. It doesn't reduce locking, it ignores the locks taken by other transactions while taking a more restrictive Schema lock on the entire table.

Comment: thank you for your comments. So is there any method you can suggest me?
Or should I finish the job in the backend instead of the database? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: You don't have anything to do if the fields are proper date types. If `StartDate` is a `date`, all you need to do is remove all conversions and just compare the fields with the date parameters, eg `StartDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @FinishDate`. If `StartDate` isn't a date, change it into a date. You have *no* guarantee that a text field would contain valid date literals.